# JQuery Object Data is filtered through multiple sliders?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, slider

I want to use a bunch of object data like this:

```
var IPAdata = {
  color: 6-14,
  ibu: 50-70,
  abv: 6.3-7.5
};
```

I'm not sure if my structure is all that correct.

Anyway, there would be three sliders: 
The first one labelled colour - ranging from 3-40
The second one labelled IBU - ranging from 0-100
The third is labelled ABV - ranging from 3-10

So ideally, when the numbers were selected from my Object Data a div would be displayed with an image inside it.

Can someone point me in the right direction, achieving this result?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to reconstruct the object it self 
you can access any object easily through

```
var IPAdata = { color: 6-14, ibu: 50-70, abv: 6.3-7.5 };
console.log(IPAdata.color);
```

but in these case the console output will be -8 ,the sum of (6-14)

if you want the value of your color

```
var IPAdata = { color: "6-14", ibu: 50-70, abv: 6.3-7.5 };
console.log(IPAdata.color);
```

output will be "6-14"

you can do whatever you want with these value

Comment: Nice! How would you go about assigning these about values to positions on the slider so that the image corresponding to this data would be displayed?

Comment: can you provide some code ,actually I didn't understand what you mean ,now you can access the values ,depends on it do whatever you want

Comment: I'm trying to flesh out / understand the code - I'll try be a bit clearer.

<div id="colour-slider">
<!--A slider in here that ranges from "3-40" -->
</div>

<div id="IBU-slider">
<!-- A slider in here ranging from 0-100 -->
</div>

<div id="ABV-Slider">
<!-- Slider here ranging from 3-10 -->
</div>

Now when the user moves the sliders to anywhere between 6-14 of the colour slider / OR 50-70 of the Ibu / OR 6.3-7.5 of the ABV I want a div to appear that has content inside it.. 

Hope this helps? haha